# iphone database using sqlite and fmdb wrapper - slow UI

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I've created a database for the iphone using sqlite and the fmdb wrapper.

The database has roughly 3500 rows in it. It has 14 columns: 1 for an id, 1 for a name/main search term, 9 other columns for alternative search terms and 3 other columns for short descriptions.

My app's first view is just an introductory screen displaying a search bar, a bit like google. After implementing the search bar, it will bring you to another view containing a table featuring the desired results. There is a 1 or 2 second delay in this initial transition between views. Furthermore, the table doesn't allow for seamless scrolling. Finally, when you select a table cell, it brings you to a final view seamlessly, but when you try to return to the table view, there is another 1 or 2 second delay.

I've run this app with a smaller database that has 3500 rows but only 5 columns. In this case, the 9 alternative search terms are deleted from the database. When I run the app like this on the iphone, it is rather efficient... there is a small delay but it really isn't noticeable... I probably wouldn't have picked up on the lag, (I would just have assumed that the small delay is normal), if it wasn't so apparent with the larger database that I use.

I've come to the conclusion that the sqlite database needs some tweaking and thus, I have two main questions.

1. Ive read that changing pragma settings, (ex: synchronous, journal mode, cache size), for the sqlite db will increase efficiency. When I change these settings via the mozilla plugin, they don't seem to save... I will open and close the plugin and the settings will revert to the old defaults. I saw that you can set these via xcode... i am wondering where in the FMDB wrapper to set these settings?
2. I've heard that indexing greatly can increase speed. I don't really know what to index though, and if I do index something, do I have to make changes in the coding of the FMDB wrapper? Furthermore, what is it that I should index considering in an ideal situation I'd like to use all the data in my database, (albeit some columns I will use differently than others)?

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Data *data = [[[DataController instance]filterDataWithName:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString:searchString]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = data.aDataName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = data.aDataStatus; 

    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)filterDataWithName:(NSString*)aDataName:(NSString*)altSearchTermA:(NSString*)altSearchTermB:(NSString*)altSearchTermC:(NSString*)altSearchTermD:(NSString*)altSearchTermE:(NSString*)altSearchTermF:(NSString*)altSearchTermG:(NSString*)altSearchTermH:(NSString*)altSearchTermI;

 {

    if ((aDataName && [aDataName length] > 0) && (altSearchTermA && [altSearchTermA length] > 0) && (altSearchTermB && [altSearchTermB length] > 0) && (altSearchTermC && [altSearchTermC length] > 0) && (altSearchTermD && [altSearchTermD length] > 0) && (altSearchTermE && [altSearchTermE length] > 0) && (altSearchTermF && [altSearchTermF length] > 0) && (altSearchTermG && [altSearchTermG length] > 0) && (altSearchTermH && [altSearchTermH length] > 0) && (altSearchTermI && [altSearchTermI length] > 0))
    {
        NSMutableArray *filterDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:dataList];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(aDataName CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermA CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermB CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermC CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermD CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermE CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermF CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermG CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermH CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (altSearchTermI CONTAINS[cd] %@)", aDataName, altSearchTermA,altSearchTermB,altSearchTermC,altSearchTermD,altSearchTermE,altSearchTermF,altSearchTermG,altSearchTermH,altSearchTermI];

        [filterDataArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
        return filterDataArray;
    }
    else
    {
        return dataList;
    }

    }
```

Comment: How do you populate your table view? Do you query for all of records at once, create the objects and keep them in memory, or do you query the database for each row when needed (scrolling table view)? Indexing is a great idea if you do searches like that.

Comment: @lawicko - i'm importing the whole sqlite database into one giant array, and from there i'm filtering it with a NSPredicate search... i have it set up so that the NSPredicate function creates it's own array based upon the search term, and this array is what is populating my table.

Comment: Ok, in this case I doubt that indexing can help you, because you fetch everything from the db anyway. Show me your *cellForRow*... method and profile your app using the time template to see what exactly takes this 2 seconds when transitioning from one view to another.

Comment: @lawicko - i've posted the code above to make it easier to read.
The first transition is taking about 1.3-1.4 seconds. objc_msgSend, which makes use of the NSPredicate function, is taking up roughly .25 seconds. When I look at memory allocations, CFString uses a great majority.

Comment: Please format the code properly. From what I can see, your problem might be filtering the entire array for each cell. Post your **filterDataWithName:** method.

Comment: @lawicko - ok, thanks for the tip. i've posted the code for the relevant method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for each cell created, so your filterDataWithName function is being called for every cell/row.

Call your filterDataWithName somewhere else, and just use the NSMutableArray in cellForRowAtIndexPath with something like

cell.textLabel.text = [[filterDataArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] data.aDataName];

Comment: thanks for the help, i really appreciate it, this fix worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I missed the problem above as mentioned by Darren - if this doesn't fix it ..... I encountered a similar problem where I needed to run an exhaustive search on table. You could try restricting your query to one row with something like this.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Level2CustomCell *cell = (Level2CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[Level2CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // SEARCH ENGINE TIME
    NSString *likeTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" TITLE LIKE '%@%@%@'",@"%",msgView.searchBar.text,@"%"];
    NSString *likeSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" SORT4='%@' AND SEARCH LIKE '%@%@%@'",selectedSection,@"%",msgView.searchBar.text,@"%"];
    NSString *likeAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" SORT4='%@' AND ADDRESS LIKE '%@%@%@'",selectedSection,@"%",msgView.searchBar.text,@"%"];
    NSString *likeContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" SORT4='%@' AND CONTENT LIKE '%@%@%@'",selectedSection,@"%",msgView.searchBar.text,@"%"];


    qry = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from SPOT_INFO WHERE SORT4 = '%@' AND %@ OR %@ OR %@ OR %@ order by TITLE limit 1 offset %d",selectedSection,likeTitle,likeSearch,likeAddress,likeContent,[indexPath row]];


    DLog(@"qry :%@",qry);

    FMResultSet *rs =   [appDelegate.userdb executeQuery:qry];

    if ([rs next]) {
        NSString *title = [rs stringForColumn:@"TITLE"];
        DLog(@"title %@",title);
        NSString *content = [rs stringForColumn:@"CONTENT"];
        NSString *imgFileName = [rs stringForColumn:@"IMG_NAME"];

    }
    [rs close];

}
```

I recommend egodatabase which has non blocking gcd (grand central dispatch) code 
https://github.com/jdp-global/egodatabase